# SVG layers into Bitmap

Tags: qt, svg

[image]

How do I save each layer as a separate PNG? 
..............................................................................................................................................................

Here's what I tried so far. It only saves the last layer.

```
int i = 0;
while(!xmlReader->atEnd() && !xmlReader->hasError()) {
        // Read next element
        QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = xmlReader->readNext();
        //If token is just StartDocument - go to next
        if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartDocument)
                continue;
        //If token is StartElement - read it
        if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement)
        {
            if(xmlReader->name() == "g")
            {
                QSvgRenderer renderer(xmlReader);

                QImage image(500, 500, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
                image.fill(Qt::transparent);

                QPainter painter(&image);
                renderer.render(&painter);
                    // Save, image format based on file extension
                image.save(QString("D:/%1.png").arg(i));
                i++;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you will likely need to transform each `<g>` element into a standalone `<SVG>` node with the `<g>` node embedded within it.

Comment: @selbie That's what I thought as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QSvgRenderer` can [render()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html#render-2) a specific named element (like an object or group) from within a file. The element name would be the `id` attribute value of each `<g>` element.

The size of an element (bounding box) can be obtained with [boundsOnElement()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html#boundsOnElement).

You could create one `QSvgRenderer(const QString &filename)` using the whole SVG source file, and then `render()` the individual elements from it as you iterate over the XML. Unfortunately I don't see any way to iterate using `QSvgRenderer` itself.

```cpp
QSvgRenderer renderer(svgFile);
...
while (...) {
  ...
  if (xmlReader->name() == "g" && xmlReader->attributes()->hasAttribute("id")) 
  {
     const QString elementId = xmlReader->attributes()->value("id");
     const QSize elementSize = renderer.boundsOnElement(id).size().toSize();
     QImage image(elementSize, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
     ...
     renderer.render(&painter, elementId);
     image.save(QString("D:/%1.png").arg(elementId));
  }
}
```